# rowHasChanged Undefined is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I'm creating a grid and I have this constructor in my class

```
export class Grid extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        var ds = new ListView.Datasource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
        this.state = {dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._genRows({}))}
    }
.
.
.
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run this:

> Undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new)
>   _reactNative.ListView.Datasource({rowHasChanged:function rowHasChanged(r1,r2){returnr1!==r2;}})')

Can someone give me a hand on this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `DataSource` instead of `Datasource`

Comment: @Cherniv you really should put that in as the answer...because its the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is just a typo. Try using `DataSource` instead of `Datasource` in this line:

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource( ...
```

`ListView` reference: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen to me and it took me a while to figure out this error so I'll write it out so other can use it.

What I had:

```
import foo from './foo'

class bar extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const foo = new foo(); // getting foo is undefined and not a constructor
  }
}
```

So apparently in js that local assignment overwrites the outer one before the call to the constructor.